# Switch Property in Google Analytics to another Account, possible?

Tags: google-analytics

My Google Analytics has an Account with multiple Properties (websites). Is it possible to switch a Property to another Account? So I can add users that don't have access to the other Properties in the Account. See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1hekbfljpob687/Schermafdruk%202014-10-14%2009.48.56.png?dl=0

Comment: You can give a user access to just one property.  You cant move the data from one account to another.

Comment: Then the user can't edit the "filters". That is the thing that should be be possible :)

Comment: Have you tried giveing them edit access on the profile in question? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en

Comment: Then the "Filters" part is disabled: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfrftghkuvbat96/Schermafdruk%202014-10-14%2010.25.28.png?dl=0

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATED ANSWER**: Google enabled [moving between accounts in September 2016](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/09/improved-analytics-administration-via.html), (tip by [smocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39580540/139040)):

> **Ownership Transfers**
>
> Many customers may have had a third party (eg. an
> agency) create a property for their website inside the third party’s
> Analytics account. This effectively housed the property into an
> account that someone else owns & controls. With property moving, it’s
> now possible to move such a property outside of its original account
> and into a new one so that the property owner can have full control of
> their property.

**OLD ANSWER**

> In the [Google Analytics>Accounts and Views (Profiles)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts#organization) help
> section, you will find:
>
> You cannot migrate historical data from one account to another. Thus, if you set up an account for a web property and then later want to move tracking to a separate account, you cannot currently migrate the data from the old account to the new account.
>
> In other words, **no, you cannot move a property from one account to
> another.**

Comment: This is helpful, but what if you don't care about migrating the historical data?

Comment: @threed then just create a brand new property. it is not like you CAN migrate to begin with.

Answer (score 7):

We just [launched](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/09/improved-analytics-administration-via.html) the ability to move properties between Analytics accounts today.

Comment: I have tried doing this but when I click the "Select designation account" it doesn't show any option nor does it help to filter or type.

Comment: Same here, no accounts show up for me as options when I want to move a property.

Comment: Sam here, another useless undocumented Google feature.

Answer (score 0):

With Google Analytics you can assign specific roles to different users to access specific accounts, properties and views, and also you can assign them a view/analyse permission only or an edit permission also.

Every account, property and view has a user management at the admin section, [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzRCj.png)

Comment: Yes, but you can only access the "Filter" part if the user has access to all Properties in an Account. 
For example: Account A has 3 Properties (website), 1 Property should be accessible for a User to edit Filters under Account. That is only possible when the User can access all 3 Properties, not just one.