# Is there a way to move Google Analytics Property to a new account?

Tags: google-analytics, admin

When I originally created my Google analytics account I added all my websites (properties) to the one account. Now I would like to move them to their own individual accounts but I cant seem to find anywhere where this option is available.

I can easily make a new account but that seems to entail creating a new property and view. If possible I would like to keep the historical data that GA has already gathered for this website.

Note: I am using the terms as per the 3 columns in the GA Admin page: Account, Property and View

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch Property in Google Analytics to another Account, possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355378/switch-property-in-google-analytics-to-another-account-possible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Update**: September 10, 2016 - Now there is a way to move GA properties between accounts:

There is no feature (at the moment) to move properties within accounts.

**Update**: January 2016 - still no feature to move properties.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need **Admin Access** to two Google Analytics ACCOUNTS - one destination account and the account where the Property currently is.

Once you have access to both with the same Google account, head in to the Property Settings and click "Move Property".

[This post has detailed instructions and a video example](https://tillison.co.uk/blog/how-to-move-a-google-analytics-property-to-another-account/).