# Transferring property from other user account to my account

Tags: google-analytics

Just to start, I am aware of the following answers but neither solves the issues I'm facing:

[Switch Property in Google Analytics to another Account, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355378/switch-property-in-google-analytics-to-another-account-possible/39580540#39580540)

[Is there a way to move Google Analytics Property to a new account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386483/is-there-a-way-to-move-google-analytics-property-to-a-new-account)

---

So I current have full access to my own GA account, let's call "Account 1" and Account 1 has "Property 1". I also have full access to my colleagues GA account called "Account 2" and has a property called "Property 2". It's setup like below:

[image]

What I'm looking for is to transfer Property 2 into Account 1. So the setup would look like this:

[image]

Now, when I try the `Transfer Property` button in GA, I keep getting `Internal Error` response from GA. Is it even possible to transfer a property that I have full access to but did not create, into an account I created?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your question I tried moving property and this is how I solved the issue.

The error keeps appearing because the property has been moved but you are still checking account 2 which has no properties. Go to admin and select account 1. if you don't need account 2 just delete it.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I cannot move the property out of account 2 and into account 1. That's when the error appears